# What should it look like when one of the host failed for zookeeper when building zk connections in java

Tags: java, database-connection, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I have the code like the following:

```
ZooKeeperInstance inst = new ZooKeeperInstance(this.instance, this.zkServers);
Connector this.conn = inst.getConnector(this.user, new PasswordToken(this.password));
```

(this.zkServers is a list of zk host separated by comma;
ZookeeperInstance is from the package of "org.apache.accumulo.core.client")

When one of the host from this.zkServers is died, but the other two host still work, these two lines just failed to connect. Does anyone know how to explain this? Thanks.

Does that mean that accumulo connection needs all the hosts in zookeeper to keep alive?

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed this behavior. You should be able to connect if you remove the dead server from your `zkServers` connection string.

It is unfortunate that Accumulo does not fail over to the next server, perhaps someone should file a bug report.